# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I get an error

> Procedure or function "myStoreProcNameHere" has too many arguments specified.

Below is my stored procedure and `SqlDataSource`. I'm using a GridView to edit data.

Help? :(

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateTwoTables 
    (@ID int, 
     @UserID varchar(10), 
     @Pass varchar(50), 
     @Enabled int, 
     @Permission int,
     @Rank int,
     @FName varchar(50),
     @LName varchar(50),
     @Phone varchar(50),
     @Email1 varchar(50),
     @Email2 varchar(50)
    ) 
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE tbl_user_login 
    SET UserID = @UserID, Pass = @Pass, 
        Enabled = @Enabled, Permission = @Permission, 
        Rank = @Rank 
    WHERE ID = @ID

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK 
        RETURN
    END

    UPDATE tbl_user_profile 
    SET FName = @FName, LName = @LName, 
        Phone = @Phone, Email1 = @Email1, Email2 = @Email2 
    WHERE ID = @ID

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN
    END

    COMMIT
```

ASP.NET `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT tbl_user_login.ID, tbl_user_login.UserID, tbl_user_login.Pass, tbl_user_login.Enabled, tbl_user_login.Permission, tbl_user_login.Rank, tbl_user_profile.ID AS Expr1, tbl_user_profile.FName,
tbl_user_profile.LName, tbl_user_profile.Phone, tbl_user_profile.Email1, tbl_user_profile.Email2 FROM tbl_user_login INNER JOIN tbl_user_profile ON tbl_user_login.ID = tbl_user_profile.ID" 
        UpdateCommand="UpdateTwoTable" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserID"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Pass"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Enabled"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Permission"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Rank"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FName"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="LName"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Phone"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email1"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email2"/>
        </UpdateParameters>        
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: [How to troubleshoot ‘Procedure or function has too many arguments specified’](http://www.whitworth.org/2006/01/16/how-to-troubleshoot-procedure-or-function-has-too-many-arguments-specified-in-aspnet-20/)

Comment: @JordanArron that link is broken and useless even if it wasn't as it just states "This usually means what it says, that your update, delete or insert command is trying to pass more parameters than the stored "

Answer (score 10):

I've ran into this error message before when I was calling a stored procedure from within a loop (foreach).

The cause of the exception that I received was due to the fact that I wasn't clearing the Parameter's after each iteration of the loop.

For example:
This code throws:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "MySproc";
    foreach (MyClass c in myClasses)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", c.val1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", c.val2);
        var result = MyDbManager.instance.ExecuteScalarQuery(cmd);
    }
}
```

The fix was to clear the parameters:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "MySproc";
    foreach (MyClass c in myClasses)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", c.val1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", c.val2);
        var result = MyDbManager.instance.ExecuteScalarQuery(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! This problem has been KILLING ME!! I couldn't figure out why the first loop worked but none of the others did.

Answer (score 0):

**Must of instance Create**

Vb.Net & C#

**glopal value**

```
vb.net -> Dim cmd as New SqlCommand()

c#-> Sqlcommand cmd=new sqlCommand()

Con.open()

cmd=New SqlCommand()

something write...

Con.Close()
```